# How to input text into web browse and click on the image from c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have some question about web browser and c#.

I open web browser like this:

```
 Process browser = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo object1 = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe", "http://www.mediabanken.se/Site/Start.aspx")
            browser.StartInfo = object1;
            browser.Start();
```

I do not know how to insert text to search field?

[image][image]

After I insert text, I have to get this:
[image]

And how to click on the image?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to get the search result? Is it okay to just display it on the browser?

Comment: After I insert text in search field I press ENTER from c#, and results are displaying, but i do not know how to press on image which is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `WindSystem.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` controll if you want to programmatically controll web page elements in C#.

For example, my form application is like this. It has `WebBrowser`, `Button` and `TextBox` controlls

[image]

and source code to archieve your questions like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttonSearch.Click += buttonSearch_Click;
}

private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    string url = "http://www.mediabanken.se/Site/Start.aspx";
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}

private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check the search results are shown 
    string className = "ProductImageControl_Image";
    // Get all "img" elements
    HtmlElementCollection images = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
    // Select the image with "ProductImageControl_Image" class
    HtmlElement image = images.Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetAttribute("className") == className);
    if (image != null)  // result image has been shown
    {
        // Click the image
        image.InvokeMember("click");
        // Unregister handler
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }
    else
    {
        // Get all input elements
        HtmlElementCollection inputs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        // Select "txtSearch" input
        HtmlElement input = inputs["txtSearch"];
        if (input != null)
        {
            string value = input.GetAttribute("VALUE");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                // Already searched but no results
            }
            else
            {
                // Input search text
                string searchText = textBoxSearch.Text;
                input.SetAttribute("VALUE", searchText);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to login to the site at http://www.mediabanken.se/Site/login.aspx before doing this though.